# Userform OptionButtons exclusive in two directions

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with buttons organized like a table in colums and rows. I want only one button activated for each column and row.
For now it works with all buttons being option buttons and all optionbuttons of a row in the same frame.
Then for the columns, I started to write for each button a sub of the type :

```
Private Sub Col1Row3_Click()

For i = 1 To 2
 Me.Controls("col1Row" & i) = False
Next i

For i = 4 To 14
 Me.Controls("col1Row" & i) = False
Next i

End Sub
```

It works, but I'm fairly confident there is a more elegant way. Any thoughts ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple sub procedure**

Tried to demonstrate a simple way to simplify code remaining close to your approach by

1. using a sub procedure
2. setting all option buttons to False in a loop and eventually the active one to True again.

```
Sub Only(ByVal rowNum As Long, ByVal colName As String, Optional ByVal maxRow As Long = 14)
' Purpose: set all OptionButtons to False except the one for row rowNum
    Dim currRow     As Long
    For currRow = 1 To maxRow
        Me.Controls(colName & "Row" & currRow) = False
    Next
    Me.Controls(colName & "Row" & rowNum) = True
End Sub
```

**Example call avoiding complicated loops**

```
Private Sub col1Row3_Click()
    Only 3, "col1"
End Sub
```

**Further hint**

Instead of repeating the procedure call for each of your option buttons, it would be possible to profit from class programming (~> `WithEvents`). For deeper insight you might be interested e.g. in [VBA Control arrays](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays) if you want to group controls that share the same name type and the same event procedures pre-defined in a class.

Comment: Oh, so vab controls array are a thing... I feel stupid.

Comment: The step by step for for an almost identical case is explained here:
https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/vba-control-arrays.htm

I'll try to adapt with one array per column and post the code, if it can be of any help for someone else.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Another hint: corrected the default argument `maxRow` in sub `Only` to 14 as this seems to be your constant value - @Groumpf

Answer (score 0):

So, just to answer my question thanks to the help of T.M., in case it could help someone else (or in case someone has something cleaner to propose).

I found two possibilities:

To allow only one selection for each column and row, if the controls are Option buttons:

- Have each row or column in a frame, lets say row for this exemple
- Have a class with the control as property and a control_click as method. The method checks all the controls of the column (column found by name if the controls.name are of type "Name" & variable & numcolumn, or thanks to a property number of colum).

The general case for all types of controls and fuck it, I didn't expect to struggle that much with checkboxes which take any change as a click.

- Have a class with the control as property and control_click as method. The method checks all the rows and columns thanks to an array as property of the class Arr(row of control, col of control), or just thanks to the name with the controls named "Name" & row & col

Exemple for checkboxes named CheckBoxRxCy (i.e. CheckBoxR01C01)

In a module (I use a defines to declare everything)

```
Public ClickCtrl  As Boolean 'the boolean which prevents the checkbox from going crazy
```

In the class ClassForExclusives (classe which handles the event when tickbox is modified)

```
Public WithEvents ControlExcl As MSForms.CheckBox       'the control with events enabled


Private Sub ControlExcl_Click()

If ClickCtrl = False Then       'inhibits reaction to value change
GoTo line1

Else
For Each control2 In UserForm1.Controls

    If control2.Name <> ControlExcl.Name Then  'avoid setting the tickbox xhanged to false

        If Right(control2.Name, 2) = Right(ControlExcl.Name, 2) Or Mid(control2.Name, 10, 2) _
        = Mid(ControlExcl.Name, 10, 2) Then 'same row/col
        ClickCtrl = False
        control2.Value = False

        End If

    End If

ClickCtrl = True 'allows the clicks to trigger the code again

Next control2
End If

line1:

End Sub
```

In the userform

```
Dim ArrControls() As New ClassForExclusives         'Set the array with the controls as ClassForExclusives

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ClickCtrl = True

For Each Chkbox In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf Chkbox Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve ArrControls(1 To i)
        Set ArrControls(i).ControlExcl = Chkbox

    End If
Next Chkbox
End Sub
```